# Nested Loops (ng-repeat) in AngularJS with $index

Tags: angularjs

Lets say we have two ng-repeat (nested) in angularJS:

```
<div ng-repeat="animal of animals track by $index">
    <div ng-repeat="name in names">
        <p>{{$index}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this example the $index would be the index of the child loop in names, but i want to have the index of the parent loop animals where i have the track by.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
  <div ng-repeat="animal of animals track by $index">
        <div ng-repeat="name in names">
            <p>{{$parent.$index}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```